# Very low quality flag failed

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I reviewed a few other VLQ flag failures and it came down to a post needing to be deleted because it is *that bad*. I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398694/setting-border-in-css-3) as very low quality.

1. There is no code
2. It is a request "i want to do what is in this picture"
   [image]
3. Even if the picture was edited into the question, and not a link, we have no clue what the user wants.
4. 18% of the viewers downvoted / cast close votes.

Does anyone believe there is a chance for a post like this to get an answer, even with **massive** edits?

[Flag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2232744)

Comment: Users at that rep level can't include images in their questions. I agree with the rest. And isn't the question closed anyway?

Comment: @BDL Yes I tried to phrase my #3 in a way to say that even if the community edited the post to include the image in the post it is not even a descriptive picture.

Comment: You haven't linked to the actual review.

Comment: @Servy sorry i have not done that before, does this suffice? http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2232744

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone believe there is a chance for a post like this to get an answer, even with massive edits?

It's possible, but unlikely. Deleted.

Comment: Does this revert my VLQ flag failure? Do I need to worry about the flag failure? My concern is now if I try to flag something it says be careful my last flag failed. Trying to avoid punishment for failed flags.

Comment: No. And no. @Jordan

Comment: @jordan the worst that can happen due to declined flags us you get a week's time out from flagging. Unless you fail really spectacularly (swearwords aplenty and such) when casting a custom flag.